# Traversing the DOM in Angular 4 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I need help in updating the CSS for selectedElement, currently, this works but only for the first element.

Basically, I have a link, when I click on it:

```
(click)="showUserDetails($event)"
```

I'm passing the x & y coordinates to my method and want to use this to update the css and enabled a boolean flag which shows the div:

```
  showUserDetails(el: any) {
let target = el.target || el.srcElement;
  let selectUsername = (document.getElementById('userDetailsInfo') as HTMLInputElement);
  selectUsername.style.top = target.offsetY + "px";
  selectUsername.style.left = target.offsetX + "px";
  this.selected = true;
  el.preventDefault();
```

}

Currently, the above code only seems to work for the first element and I'm trying to figure out a way to have it so based on the clicked element, go up the dom and find me the div with the id of 'userDetailsInfo' and apply the top/left values to that, and not just to the first item.

Comment: You could fire a custom event, which contains the new coordinates, which the other components are listening to and then update them ?

Comment: In angular components are very encapsulated with few points of interaction. You can either fire an event chain like Zze mention or have a containing component manage the event and control the sub components. You can do your own event management with RXJS on the component.

Comment: If it's not for a specific component you can run a one off script independent of angular and load it via whatever you use to build your site. If you use angluar cli it would be .angular-cli.json>"apps">"scripts". Just a note, writing script to change DOM is a code smell in Angular, should change component model to change dom.

Comment: don't use JQuery just [ngStyle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it like so:

```
  private hostEl: HTMLElement;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
      this.hostEl = el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
  }

  //Get the header
  let header = (document.querySelector('.header') as HTMLInputElement);

  if (window.pageYOffset >= 100){
      header.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
      header.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
```